# Why spring boot is loading another component even though i am not importing explicitly?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm not using `@import` annotation though context is able to load the bean (SalesService) it should throw the exception find the code.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = (ApplicationContext) SpringApplication.run(CustomerConfig.class);
        CustomerService customer = (CustomerService) context.getBean("customerBean");
        customer.printMessage("setting message for CustomerService");
        SalesService sales = (SalesService)context.getBean("salesBean");
        sales.printMessage("setting message for SalesService");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Anntotation `@SpringBootApplication` does a `@ComponentScan` on the package off the annotated class.

This means that every @Component,@Controller, @Service in the same or subpacke gets instantiated.

Have a look [here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html).

You can controll it by providing attributes to `@SpringBootApplication'.
[Docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html)

Comment: Hi, i tried by removing @SpringBootApplication still it is initializing Saleconfig.

Comment: When I remove `@SpringBootApplication` (and with that the inherited `@EnableAutoConfiguration` my application does not start anymore: `Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.` So you must do something different